# Trying to implement a worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I need to read data from a table and do some work on each row and mark the row as updated. I don't want to read the updated row again. Here is what I am planning to do with a ExecutorService. Is this correct ?

Thanks.

```
public class ScheduledDBPoll
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        /* Connect to database. */
        while (true)
        {
        /* Issue a select statment for un-updated rows. */
            /* Get the primary key. */

            service.submit(new Task(primaryKey));      /* Pass the primary key*/
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);     /* Sleep for 3 seconds. */
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(ScheduledDBPoll.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        /* Close the connection here. */
    }
}

final class Task implements Runnable
{
    private int taskId;

    public Task(int primayKey)
    {
        this.taskId = primayKey;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            /* Connect to database. */
            /* Select the passed primary key row. */
            /* Do some work,  mark the row as updated. */
            /* Close the connection here. */            
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Task.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Firebird database, Firebird is only thread safe at the connection level. So I am trying to avoid having two queries in different threads running against the same connection. I also forgot to mention that the above piece of code is going to run as a windows service, so it will be always looking for newly inserted records.

Comment: when I see `while(true){...}` then I know something's wrong

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be complete.. Are you gonna run this forever? No condition to terminate `while(true){...}`.. and from where `primaryKey` is initialized?

Comment: I am fearing of `primary key`! would you please explain a little more about the business.!?

Comment: Updated; please have a look!

Answer (score 1):

I would uses a ScheduledExecutorService and not have a thread which sends the job every three second.  I would also keep the connection open as creating a database connection is very slow.

So I would implement it more like

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


final class Task implements Runnable {
    private Connection connection;
    private int taskId;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (!connectionIsOkay()) {
                connectToDatabase();
                taskId = selectUnUpdatedRow();
            }
            selectRowsToUpdate();
            processRowsToUpdate();
            markAsUpdated();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Task.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    // TODO find a more elegant way to close the connection when finished.
    public void finalise() {
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated; please take a look!

Comment: @Sudheer I don't see anything which might change my answer, other than you don't need the `finalise()` method

Comment: I am using Firebird database, Firebird is only thread safe at the connection level. So I am trying to avoid having two queries in different threads running against the same connection. I also forgot to mention in my first post that the above piece of code is going to run as a windows service, so it will be always looking for newly inserted records, that is why the for 3 seconds after each select.

Answer (score 0):

First, a terminology issue, which may be important: This code does not implement "a" worker thread; it tries to do concurrent database access from up to 10 threads simultaneously.

So if you really *did* actually only want one worker thread, your fixed thread pool needs to be of size 1, not 10. But then you might not need separate tasks, you can possibly have one task for everything and the whole thing becomes simpler.

I don't know why you're waiting for 3 seconds (actually it's one second despite what your comment says), that seems pointless.

Other than that, it seems correct.